# ItemInvoked vs SelectionChanged

Tags: events, uwp, navigation, uwp-xaml

In Windows UWP, what is the difference between the `ItemInvoked` and `SelectionChanged` events for a `NavigationView`? The [API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview) states

> **ItemInvoked**
>  
>   Occurs when an item in the menu receives an interaction such as a click or tap.
>
> **SelectionChanged**
>   Occurs when the currently selected item changes.

It seems to me that `SelectionChanged` can detect when navigation occurs even by some method other than clicking a `NavigationView.MenuItem`, so would be the better, more encompassing option to use?

Or are there different use cases for each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference would be that the `SelectionChanged` event is executed only once, but if you click the selected item repeatedly, it is not fired. `ItemInvoked` on the other hand will execute each time an item is clicked even if it is selected already.

Also - `SelectionChanged` event will execute when you manually set `SelectedItem` in code.

Answer (score 3):

Another thing that might be useful to note is that `ItemInvoked` fires before `SelectionChanged` when you click on a `NavigationView` item

Answer (score 1):

I was recently struggling with this question and having a problem when using the SelectionChanged Event. Successive clicks on the same Menu Item yielded no result.
Then I found this blog post (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2018/05/06/using-the-navigationview-in-your-uwp-applications/)  which suggested using the `ItemInvoked` Event for the same reason given in answer #1.
This did not work for me as posted in the Blog but after changing the code to use the `InvokedItemContainer` Tag property the solution worked just fine.
I have included the test code I used to verify the solution.

```
private void NvTopLevelNav_ItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.IsSettingsInvoked)
        {
            contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
        }
        else
        {
            string navTo = args.InvokedItemContainer.Tag.ToString();

            if ( navTo != null)
            {
                switch (navTo)
                {
                    case "Nav_Home":
                        contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(HomePage));
                        break;

                    case "Nav_Shop":
                        contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(ShopPage));
                        break;

                    case "Nav_ShopCart":
                        contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(CartPage));
                        break;

                    case "Nav_Message":
                        contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(MessagePage));
                        break;

                    case "Nav_Print":
                        contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(PrintPage));
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

<Grid>
    <NavigationView x:Name="nvTopLevelNav"
                    Loaded="NvTopLevelNav_Loaded"
                    Margin="0,12,0,0"
                    SelectionChanged="NvTopLevelNav_SelectionChanged"
                    ItemInvoked="NvTopLevelNav_ItemInvoked"
                    IsTabStop="False"
                    Header="Lets Go Shopping">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Home" Content="Home" Tag="Nav_Home" />
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Shop" Content="Shop" Tag="Nav_Shop" />
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Shopping Cart" Tag="Nav_Cart">
                <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                    <FontIcon Glyph="[Insert Hex Decimal Value Here. See Segoe MDL2 below for details.]"/>
                </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
            </NavigationViewItem>
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Message" Content="Message" Tag="Nav_Message" />
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Print" Content="Print" Tag="Nav_Print" />
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <Frame x:Name="contentFrame"></Frame>
    </NavigationView>

</Grid>
```